# Is my solution for proving $3^n > n^2$ using induction correct?

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm sharpening my math skills by myself since school never motivated me to do it, so right now I'm doing some induction exercises.

I just solved one and I'm not sure if it's right since it doesn't fit the solution I was given.

I skipped the base case.

$
3^n > n^2 , n > 2 \\
3^k > k^2 \\
3^{k+1} > (k+1)^2 \\
3^k > k^2 | \cdot 3 \\
3^{k+1} > 3k^2 \\
3k^2 > k^2 + 2k + 1 \\
2k^2 > 2k+1 \\
2k^2 - 2k > 1 \\
2k(k+1) > 1 \\
\begin{cases}k > 2 => k+1 > 1 \\2k > 1\end{cases} \implies 3^{k+1} > (k+1)^2
$

The solution I saw was more bottoms-up and mine seems to be solved top-down anyway that's why I'm wondering.

Sorry for my Tex just learned some to hack this together. Thanks for taking time to read and answer my newbie doubt.

Comment: Your solution is fine. However, it lacks statements of what steps in induction you consider (known for $k$, needs to be proved for $k+1$ etc.), similarly: what is known and what needs to be shown.

Comment: The *proper* way to write an induction step for this would be $3^{k+1}\geq \dots >^{\text{induction hypothesis}}\dots\geq (k+1)^2$ in a single line.  Starting with what you want to prove and arriving at a tautology is only mildly acceptable if you ensure that every step taken is reversible.  In general proving that a statement implies a tautology is not enough to prove that the statement is true in general.

Comment: In this case, $3^{k+1}=3\cdot 3^k>^{\text{I.H.}}3\cdot k^2=k^2+k^2+k^2>^{\dagger}k^2+2k+1=(k+1)^2$ where I.H. is true by induction hypothesis and $\dagger$ is true by the fact that $k>2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can streamline the development as follows.  First, we establish a base case.  For $n=1$, this is $3^1>1^2$.  Now, we assume that for some number $n\ge 2$ we have

$$3^n>n^2$$

Then, proceeding by induction and noting that for $n\ge 2$, $n^2\ge 2n>1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
3^{n+1}&=(3)\,3^n\\\\
&>3n^2\\\\
&=n^2+n^2+n^2\\\\
&>n^2+2n+1\\\\
&=(n+1)^2
\end{align}$$

And we are done!